# How can I stop an RxJs observable from firing until other call have completed?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```js
    this.redactedService.selectedProfile.pipe(switchMap(selectedProfile => {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.selectedProfile = selectedProfile;

      this.existingExpiredListToDisplay = [];
      this.existingFailedListToDisplay = [];
      this.existingAuthoriseListToDisplay = [];
      this.pendingExpiredList = [];
      this.pendingFailedList = [];

      return forkJoin(this.redactedService.getAuthorisationsExpired(selectedProfile.ProfileId), this.redactedService.getAuthorisationsFailed(selectedProfile.ProfileId));
    })).subscribe(([authExpired, authFailed]) => {
      this.authExpiredList$.next(authExpired);
      this.authFailedList$.next(authFailed);
    });

    zip(this.authExpiredList$, this.authFailedList$).pipe(switchMap(([authExpired, authFailed]) => {
      this.pendingExpiredList = authExpired.ExpiredPaymentsList;
      this.pendingFailedList = authFailed.FailedPaymentList;

      return this.redactedService.selectedAccount;
    }), takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(selectedAccount => {
      this.selectedAccount = selectedAccount;
      this.accountNumberForRequests = this.selectedAccount.AccountNumberForRequests;

      // filter when changing accounts
      this.filterExpiredPaymentsList(this.accountNumberForRequests, 'Expired & Failed');
    });
```

The issue I am having is due to the fact that within a parent component, if the selectedProfile changes, it changes the selectedAccount too.

So if the SelectedProfile changes, then during the execution of this code, the selectedAccount subscription fires immediately after SelectedProfile fires, but I dont want that to happen until everything related to the profile changing has fired already (making the getAuthorisationsExpired/getAuthorisationsFailed XHR calls, etc).

Is there any way I can stop the inner observable of the selectedAccount from firing before the neccesary calls have been made?

As an example of what the intended functionality is, here is a "Fix" that I just came up with, that I think works... but it seems very hacky.

```html
this.redactedService.selectedProfile.pipe(switchMap(selectedProfile => {
      this.profileJustChanged = true;
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.selectedProfile = selectedProfile;

      this.existingExpiredListToDisplay = [];
      this.existingFailedListToDisplay = [];
      this.existingAuthoriseListToDisplay = [];
      this.pendingExpiredList = [];
      this.pendingFailedList = [];

      return forkJoin(this.redactedService.getAuthorisationsExpired(selectedProfile.ProfileId), this.redactedService.getAuthorisationsFailed(selectedProfile.ProfileId));
    })).subscribe(([authExpired, authFailed]) => {
      this.authExpiredList$.next(authExpired);
      this.authFailedList$.next(authFailed);
    });

    zip(this.authExpiredList$, this.authFailedList$).pipe(switchMap(([authExpired, authFailed]) => {
    this.profileJustChanged = false;
      this.pendingExpiredList = authExpired.ExpiredPaymentsList;
      this.pendingFailedList = authFailed.FailedPaymentList;

      return this.redactedService.selectedAccount;
    }), takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(selectedAccount => {
      if(!this.profileJustChanged) {
          this.selectedAccount = selectedAccount;
          this.accountNumberForRequests = this.selectedAccount.AccountNumberForRequests;

          // filter when changing accounts
          this.filterExpiredPaymentsList(this.accountNumberForRequests, 'Expired & Failed');
      }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you are explicitly changing `selectedAccount` here: `this.selectedAccount = selectedAccount;`. If you don't want it to change why are you re-assigning it?

Comment: I want selectedAccount to change, but the the issue is the order in which things are firing. The issue is that the filterExpiredPaymentsList function depends on both the SelectedAccount as well as the results of getAuthorisationsExpired/Failed.
But the selectedAccount subscription gets fired as soon as selectedProfile changes, which is before the getAuthorisationsExpired call has finished

Comment: So when `selectedProfile` emits, this line `this.selectedAccount = selectedAccount;` will be immediately invoked?

Comment: Yes, and then the filterExpiredPaymentsList function is called too. But I dont want that to happen until the calls are completed which are kicked off when selectedProfile executes.  I have edited my post to include a "fix" which I think is a little bit too hacky

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit strange. What kind of subjects are `authExpiredList$` and `authFailedList$`? Also, do they `next` values from other places?

Comment: They are plain Subjects. They don't next values from other places. The behavior doesn't seem strange to me, its just not what I intend.

I dont think there is anything in my code to stop selectedAccount from firing. SelectedAccount is getting a new value when the SelectedProfile changes, and therefore the SelectedAccount event is firing.

Comment: This is my reasoning: `selectedProfile` emits, then those 2 subjects will emit after the observables provided to `forkJoin` would have emitted at least once & completed. Then, because both subjects emitted, `zip` also emits, which will enter the `switchMap` that will return the `redactedService.selectedAccount`. Is this correct? Could you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. 
On the first load of the page, that is the order in which everything executes, which is perfect.
The issue comes in when the selectedProfile is changed after that initial load.
Then what happens is that the initial selectedProfile observable fires, and then immediately afterwards, the selectedAccount observable fires, because the redactedService.selectedAccount changes in the parent component when selectedProfile changes, and authExpiredList$ and authFailedList$ subjects have values already (due to the initial execution on page load).

Comment: So because the 2 subjects in the zip already have values, the inner selectedAccount observable fires whenever the selectedProfile changes, but I need it to wait until the selectedProfiles calls are all completed, which isnt happening.

Comment: I will attempt to create a stackblitz. I have never used it before, so it may take me some time

Comment: If the 2 subjects are `Subject` instances, then they should not have any values in the zip, once zip emitted, unless they emit multiple times. I'd be glad to have a look once the SB is ready.

Comment: I will attempt to make a SB during the course of today. Before I do that though, are you of the impression that the inner observable of selectedAccount would only fire after the zip emits new values?
It doesnt seem to work that way. Once those zipped observables have emitted during the initial load, that inner subscription gets set up and continues firing whenever the selectedAccount changes, regardless of the zip emitting new values or not. If the zip DOES emit new values, it cancels the current selectedAccount subscription and starts a new one (due to the switchmap)